# How can I access RESTAPI in Openfire server and create user from that web service?

Tags: java

I am currently working on xmpp-openfire server with java
I want to create and delete user in openfire server using RestAPI.

I already read the document http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#create-a-user

But I can't access that using that server
I don't know the steps which should i will follow.

Comment: what is **that server** ?? How are u accessing the REST API? Any geneated URLs? Question in this shape is begging to be downvoted and closed.

Comment: @Antoniossss I forgot to enable that RestApi But now i can't open UserService Api from Restapi. Please help me.Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to upload RestAPI plugin into openfire. You can do this from plugins admin view as there is a "Available plugins` link where you will download and deploy plugin with single mouse click

Later on, you have to enable and configure the plugin is plugin management section (Admin Web Interface) where you will configure ACL and security keys.

Then you can try to access REST service via  GET http://example.org:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users
with proper headers (described in docs from link you have provided)

Comment: Thankyou so much @Antoniossss

Comment: I can't open userservice console from restapi.